# Security review team for AppExchange will stress test the app? Any thoughts please

Tags: appexchange, security-review

We are about to submit an app for the security review. I am wondering whether the security review team will do any stress or performance test on the app? What are they actually do with our code or app?

Any thoughts, please?

Thanks

Comment: There are various public documents on the security review e.g. [Security Review Steps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review.htm) that explain the focus of the process.

Comment: What Keith is trying to say is... no. They're worried about XSS, SQL injections, privilege escalation, stealing sessions, and so on. Having a slow service is not a security issue, having an insecure service is.